# Two imageview with separate onTouch Event

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two imageview in which i am adding image by using setImageBitmap and also apply setOnTouchListener to them. But here problem is that for the first time when add first img, its move by touch but when i add second img, the second img move but after that i can't move first img by touch. Sorry for english and thanks in advanced.

Comment: i think u are trying to move image on touch am i right and have u used in absolute layout or not first tell me than or what u have used on that based i will reply

Comment: @khan My both imageview is in relative layout and i want to move both image depending on which img is touch by user

Comment: but one que is on which base u move ur image using redrawaing image on touch or setting layout params on it on touch move

Comment: i m using view.setImageMatrix(matrix); for redrawing image onTouch event

Comment: i think u have also set touch event on ur relative layout am i right

Comment: please see my answer, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give onTouchListener for two image seperately as

```
 ImageView first_image=new ImageView(this);
   first_image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {

                }
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {

                }
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    //Code for image moving
                }
            return false;
        }
    });


        ImageView second_image=new ImageView(this);
    second_image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {

                }
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {

                }
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    //code for image moving
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can u please post your code so that we can understand what you have done and whats your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code for that, it may help you and use Imageview instead of Textview.

```
tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view1);
tv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv1.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams1.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams1.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view2);
tv2.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
tv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {         

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tv2.getLayoutParams();
        switch(event.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();
                if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                    x_cord = windowwidth;
                }
                if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                    y_cord = windowheight;
                }
                layoutParams2.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                layoutParams2.topMargin = y_cord - 75;
                tv2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```